# Upload an image and error on show Toast in AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, toast

i hope to put my upload image function in AsyncTask. therefore i changes, it still had error.
now,i think that my problem in onPostExecute. 
Do httpURLConnection operation need to put in onPostExecute?
what should i change? 
thank you for your help me

```
  class upload extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading....");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Saving product
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
 {
                   String end = "\r\n";  
                String twoHyphens = "--";  
                 String boundary = "******";  
            try  
            {  
              URL url = new URL(actionUrl);  
              HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url  
                  .openConnection();  
              // setting the memory
               httpURLConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode(128 * 1024);// 128K  
              // allow  input and output
              httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);  
              httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);  
              httpURLConnection.setUseCaches(false);  
              // use POST way  
              httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");  
              httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");  
              httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Charset", "UTF-8");  
              httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",  
                  "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);  

              DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(  
                  httpURLConnection.getOutputStream());  
              dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + end);  
              dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\"; filename=\""  
                  + srcPath.substring(srcPath.lastIndexOf("/") + 1)  
                  + "\""  
                  + end);  
              dos.writeBytes(end);  

              FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(srcPath);  
              byte[] buffer = new byte[8192]; // 8k  
              int count = 0;  

              while ((count = fis.read(buffer)) != -1)  
              {  
                dos.write(buffer, 0, count);  
              }  
              fis.close();  

              dos.writeBytes(end);  
              dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + end);  
              dos.flush();  

              InputStream is = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();  
              InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is, "utf-8");  
              BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);  
              String result = br.readLine();  

              dos.close();  
              is.close(); 

              return result;




            } catch (Exception e)  
            {  
              e.printStackTrace();  
              setTitle(e.getMessage());  
            } 

        }

        return null;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        // dismiss the dialog once product uupdated
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
    }
```

LOGCAT

```
     04-22 09:01:53.381: E/AndroidRuntime(1154): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
      04-22 09:01:53.381: E/AndroidRuntime(1154): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
      04-22 09:01:53.381: E/AndroidRuntime(1154):   at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
      04-22 09:01:53.381: E/AndroidRuntime(1154):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
      04-22 09:01:53.381: E/AndroidRuntime(1154):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
      04-22 09:01:53.381: E/AndroidRuntime(1154):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
      04-22 09:01:53.381: E/AndroidRuntime(1154):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
      04-22 09:01:53.381: E/AndroidRuntime(1154):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
      04-22 09:01:53.381: E/AndroidRuntime(1154):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
      04-22 09:01:53.381: E/AndroidRuntime(1154):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
      04-22 09:01:53.381: E/AndroidRuntime(1154): Caused by: android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
      04-22 09:01:53.381: E/AndroidRuntime(1154):   at android.view.ViewRoot.checkThread(ViewRoot.java:2802)
      04-22 09:01:53.381: E/AndroidRuntime(1154):   at android.view.ViewRoot.invalidateChild(ViewRoot.java:607)
      04-22 09:01:53.381: E/AndroidRuntime(1154):   at android.view.ViewRoot.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRoot.java:633)
      04-22 09:01:53.381: E/AndroidRuntime(1154):   at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:2505)
      04-22 09:01:53.381: E/AndroidRuntime(1154):   at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:5139)
      04-22 09:01:53.381: E/AndroidRuntime(1154):   at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:5364)
      04-22 09:01:53.381: E/AndroidRuntime(1154):   at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2688)
      04-22 09:01:53.381: E/AndroidRuntime(1154):   at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2556)
      04-22 09:01:53.381: E/AndroidRuntime(1154):   at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2531)
      04-22 09:01:53.381: E/AndroidRuntime(1154):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setTitle(PhoneWindow.java:260)
     04-22 09:01:53.381: E/AndroidRuntime(1154):    at android.app.Activity.onTitleChanged(Activity.java:3581)
      04-22 09:01:53.381: E/AndroidRuntime(1154):   at android.app.Activity.setTitle(Activity.java:3547)
      04-22 09:01:53.381: E/AndroidRuntime(1154):   at com.example.mmap.MainActivity$upload.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:255)
      04-22 09:01:53.381: E/AndroidRuntime(1154):   at com.example.mmap.MainActivity$upload.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
      04-22 09:01:53.381: E/AndroidRuntime(1154):   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
      04-22 09:01:53.381: E/AndroidRuntime(1154):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
      04-22 09:01:53.381: E/AndroidRuntime(1154):   ... 4 more
      04-22 09:01:54.411: E/WindowManager(1154): Activity com.example.mmap.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@46047368 that was originally added here
      04-22 09:01:54.411: E/WindowManager(1154): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.mmap.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@46047368 that was originally added here
      04-22 09:01:54.411: E/WindowManager(1154):    at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:247)
      04-22 09:01:54.411: E/WindowManager(1154):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:148)
      04-22 09:01:54.411: E/WindowManager(1154):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
      04-22 09:01:54.411: E/WindowManager(1154):    at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
      04-22 09:01:54.411: E/WindowManager(1154):    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
      04-22 09:01:54.411: E/WindowManager(1154):    at com.example.mmap.MainActivity$upload.onPreExecute(MainActivity.java:187)
      04-22 09:01:54.411: E/WindowManager(1154):    at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:391)
      04-22 09:01:54.411: E/WindowManager(1154):    at com.example.mmap.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:68)
      04-22 09:01:54.411: E/WindowManager(1154):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
      04-22 09:01:54.411: E/WindowManager(1154):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
      04-22 09:01:54.411: E/WindowManager(1154):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
     04-22 09:01:54.411: E/WindowManager(1154):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
      04-22 09:01:54.411: E/WindowManager(1154):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
      04-22 09:01:54.411: E/WindowManager(1154):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
      04-22 09:01:54.411: E/WindowManager(1154):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
      04-22 09:01:54.411: E/WindowManager(1154):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
      04-22 09:01:54.411: E/WindowManager(1154):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
      04-22 09:01:54.411: E/WindowManager(1154):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
      04-22 09:01:54.411: E/WindowManager(1154):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: show your error, that will be easy to solve your problem

Comment: What does this function do setTitle(e.getMessage());. Update ui ??

Comment: Are you getting result in `onPostExecute()`??

Comment: i have to upload the logCAT

Comment: @HimYikTang setTitle(e.getMessage()); does the function update ui? It seems you are updating ui from the background thread. You need to update ui on the Ui thread. Do it in onPostExecute()

Comment: @Raghunandan how do i put update in onPostExecute() ?

Comment: suppose i have textview. i return result in doinBackground say a string "hello".You would returning string in doInBackground() return result; The result of doInBackgroud() is a parameter to onPostExecute(String result) then in onPostExecute() textView.setText(result);

Answer (score 2):

Remove the return result, because you cannot return from child view. 
    remove

`setTitle(e.getMessage());`

from doinbackground 
    And rewrite postexecute like this

```
protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
    // dismiss the dialog once product uupdated
    pDialog.dismiss();
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }
```

Comment: i remove the return result also the problem still observe

Comment: Remove setTitle(e.getMessage()); also

Comment: and remove unnecessary bracket after doninBackground

Comment: THANK YOU i have success to upload image,but the toast never show any test.

Comment: write toast after dialog.dismiss() and toast the result. you can store result in variable in doinbackground method and show it in onPostexecte method

Comment: @Shyam no need to store the result in another variable. the result is a parameter to onPostExecute(String result) which can be used to display toast. Also you answer does not dwell on  setTitle(e.getMessage());  which is attempting to update ui on the background thread

Comment: @Raghunandan i already mention in comment to remove setTitle(e.getMessage()); from doinbackground :)

Comment: @Shyam  i din't understand this part "because you cannot return from child view" of your answer

Comment: @Raghunandan because you cannot update UI from parent view class. that mean doinbackground not use main thread.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28648/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-shyam)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this method:

```
setTitle(e.getMessage());
```

Is accessing UI Thread from outside of it.
All that touchech UI must be done outside of doInBackground() method.